# How to read float value on width size?

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

currently i need to set the width of column based on exported data. i found errors indicates that it cannot read float on width sizing.

```
   foreach($this->dataCols->all() as $columnName => $columnInfo)
{
                
                $width = floatval($columnInfo['width']) / 1;

                //width
                array_push($requests,
                new \Google\Service\Sheets\Request([
                    "updateDimensionProperties" => [
                        "range" => [
                            "sheetId" => $sheet_id,
                            "startIndex" => 0,
                            "endIndex" => (sizeof($this->dataCols->all())),
                            "dimension" => "COLUMNS",
                        ],
                        "properties" => ["pixelSize" => $width],
                        "fields" => "pixelSize",
                    ],
                ]),
            );

  }
```

Here is the error message:

"message": "Invalid value at 'requests[5].update_dimension_properties.properties.pixel_size' (TYPE_INT32), 2.3076923076923075

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error message of `"message": "Invalid value at 'requests[5].update_dimension_properties.properties.pixel_size' (TYPE_INT32), 2.3076923076923075`, it is considered that the reason for your current issue is due to the value of `$width`.

When we see the official document of [DimensionProperties](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#dimensionproperties), the following document can be seen.

> pixelSize: integer
> The height (if a row) or width (if a column) of the dimension in pixels.

From your error message, it seems that `$width` is `2.3076923076923075`. I think that this is the reason for your issue. So, in this case, please modify this as the integer.

So, as a sample modification for testing your request, please modify as follows and test it again.

#### From:

```
"properties" => ["pixelSize" => $width],
```

#### To:

```
"properties" => ["pixelSize" => 200],
```

- By this modification, I think that your script works without the error.

#### Note:

- From your error message, I think that the value of `2.3076923076923075` is very small for the column width. For example, when `$width` is `2`, it is difficult to see the cell value. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [DimensionProperties](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#dimensionproperties)